# removeAttribute not removing CSS style

Tags: javascript, html, css

removeAttribute is not removing the "display: none;" in #hamburger-menu

`JS:`

```
const hamburgerMenu = document.getElementById("hamburger-menu");
const hamburger = document.getElementById("hamburger");

hamburger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    hamburgerMenu.removeAttribute("display");
});
```

Comment: The "display" property is on the element's `style` object, not the element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `hamburger.style.display = ''`.

`display` is a style of the element, not an attribute.

Comment: I heavily suggest never changing the inline styles unless there is no other choice. It makes further changes to the styling very hard in some cases - something that should take 5 minutes and a couple of lines of CSS turns into an hour of finding where the inline style is being set.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing display property, set a new value to it like block, flex, etc. Actually, it's usually a better idea to toggle a class to change CSS. By doing so, you can manipulate multiple styles very easily.

```css
#hamburger-menu.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

```js
hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    hamburgerMenu.classList.toggle("visible");
});
```